# Cannot see files copied to C: (system drive) in Windows 7

Tags: file, windows-7, copy

Could someone can explain me why can't I see a file copied to C:?

Note that if I try to copy it again to the same location, the system ask me if I want to override it.

Not a matter of weird attributes, or common stuffs ;)

Hope I can find an answer here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved,

I noted there was a magic "Compatibility files" link in the tool bar. Just clicked on it and the files I had copied suddenly showed up their faces.

Thanks anyway,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've set the file of that extension to be hidden? Does it appear with the 'dir /H' command?

Comment: When you type dir /h there comes an error: Invalid switch. Instead you should use: dir /ah

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to refresh the folder - use `F5`.

Alternatively, if the file is hidden, you may need to "show hidden files".

To do that, hold down `alt` -> `Tools` menu -> `Folder options` -> `View` -> `Show hidden files and folders`.